# Linking error for mixed macOs app with static libs (swift, objc, c++)

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos, linker

I have two static libraries and one **macOs** App (all under latest XCode 8.1).

1) First lib (**A**), is **ObjC++** (mixed objc and c++/stl)

2) Second (**B**) is pure **ObjC**, and contains some common categories (for NSObject for example)

3) The App is Swift and use both libs

All targets builds with the same c++ flags (libc++11 and so on), the problem is:

1) if I add **-ObjC** (and/or) **-load_all** linker flags to the **App** (to normal linkage with lib **B** categories), then i got many "*Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64*" (all about STL)

2) if i remove this linker flags, then **App** compile normal, but in runtime i'v got "*missing selector*" for all lib **B** categories.

However, if i completely remove lib **B** (adding all of its sources directly in the **App**) and respectively remove **-ObjC**/**-load_all**, then the problem with the STL linking is solved, but unfortunately this is not the right option for me.  So I hope for your help, or at least an explanation of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Append `-lc++` (standard C++ lib) to `Other Linker Flags` in `Build Settings` of your app and see if that solves the problem.  Without knowing more about your app and libs, I'm not sure what's going on, but I would speculate that when `-ObjC` is added, causing additional code from `libB` to be loaded, then some symbols from the standard C++ library are somehow needed, but not available.

Alternatively you can add `libc++.tbd` in the `Link Binary With Libraries` section in the `Build Phases` of the app.  It's available in the frameworks and libraries list that comes up when you click the + sign in that section.